# Who or what was Silas from "The Graveyard Book"?

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-graveyard-book

Having read "The Graveyard Book" by Neil Gaiman recently did make me wonder who or what was Silas' beside the obvious - Nobody's guardian.

Comment: I think Silas is a vampire as well. and The Dracula's son theory is very... appealing to me. Shortly after getting about halfway through the book I theorized that he was a vampire. Besides, a Turned vampire would go mad with hunger, but Turned vampires can't cast a Glamour. So, Yeah, I think I agree with him being Dracula's son. The only thing I want to know is this; why didn't he return home sooner? After all, the book takes place in the twenty-first century.

Comment: He is in many ways Bagheera

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [Neil Gaiman's website Q&A](http://www.mousecircus.com/bookdetails.aspx?BookID=1):

> Q: What is Silas in THE GRAVEYARD
>   BOOK?
>
> A: Silas is a Very Important
>   Character in THE GRAVEYARD BOOK. Also,
>   he is Bod’s Guardian.

That would seem to be the official answer.

Some sources on the internet, such as the [LA Times](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/2010/01/22/neil-gaiman-graveyard-book-movie/), seem to think he is a vampire:

> He [Neil Gaiman] also wanted to emphasize that,
>   despite some trying times, he will not
>   arrive at Royce Hall as glum as, say,
>   Silas, the dour vampire who becomes an
>   orphan’s protector in “The Graveyard
>   Book.”

This [discussion board post](http://neilgaimanboard.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/91510584541/m/70210981741?r=49410033741#49410033741) lays out some convincing evidence:

> Silas is a vampire. He doesn't go out
>   during the day, sleeps in a coffin,
>   eats only one kind of food (and it's
>   not bananas! Wink), avoids rain (in
>   old myths vamps can't stand running
>   water), and has no reflection. He's
>   also directly stated as being neither
>   living nor dead.

Comment: He also does have power of persuasion which does tie in to him being the Vampire.

Answer (score 2):

Silas is definitely a vampire.  He only eats one type of food (blood), says he has done terrible things in his past (probably turning other people into vampires), never goes out into the Sun, and has no reflection (in the caves under Krakow and when he and Bod went out for pizza after the Jacks were all gone).

Answer (score 1):

100% vampire. Although, there are lots of stories as to how he became a vampire. Some people say he is actually Dracula, and others say he was just turned into a vampire.

The Dracula theory is false, seeing how Dracula died in the 1800's. As for him being turned, I don't think that is true, either. He specifically stated that he had done horrible things to people in the past, and if I were turned, I wouldn't hurt people. I'd probably just hide in a corner and cry myself to sleep. Which leads me to this conclusion:

Silas is the son of Dracula. This makes sense. Dracula was killed by humans, and Silas, who was a loyal son, wanted revenge. After slaughtering people, something made him realize what he was doing was horrible, (Perhaps he met Miss Lupescu, who convinced him that what he was doing was wrong. considering he has a strange but settle fondness towards her in the book.) Silas wanted to make up for what he had done, so he joined the Honour Guard. He tried to return home, but couldn't, because people weren't too fond of him at the time. That is why he was in the old chapel, and that's how he met Bod. You don't have to believe me, but just consider it.

Comment: I would just like to point out that that is why Silas took in the boy as, essentially, his son. Silas knew what the death of a family could do to a person, and wanted Bod to grow up as a peaceful person, not the murderer Silas once was.

Comment: What supporting evidence of this is there in the books? Having just read it I recall no mention of dracula at all. Its a theory that works but I can't think of any reason that this could be considered a canonical answer...

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I had a totally different take. My feeling was that Silas was *Death* itself. You could take that line about him only eating one kind of food and postulate that the one thing he consumes is actually life. He is described as being something not quite from either world. His status among the ghosts and his power and influence over both the living and the dead seems to indicate he is something much more than a mere bloodsucker. His lines all reminded me of the narrator from the Book Thief.

Comment: Nah. Death is Gray Lady. Silas is a vampire.

Answer (score 0):

He is a Vampire. When he is in the catacombs he walks in to the mirror trap and is not consumed by it. Also, in the beginning he said:

> I wouldn't know what a banana tastes like. **I only eat one kind of food, and a banana is not it**.

Comment: Hello @user55552 and welcome to scifi&fantasy SE. As you kindly did, the answer section is reserved for detailed answers backed with evidence and proofs.To ask for details about an answer or a question you may use the comments below. There's a helpful tour under the help button. Enjoy your stay, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think silas is a vampire because at the beginning of chapter 6 -I think- it started off as rain dripping off the gutter and hitting the windows and then it said that silas was hiding in one of the darkest corners of the chapel

Answer (score 0):

Although Neil Gaiman himself has never confirmed it, Silas is clearly a vampire. He is dark and silent, sleeps in a large trunk filled with soil, avoids daylight, has no reflection, dresses in black velvet,  only consumes "one food" (presumably blood), can be stuck by a car without sustaining serious injuries, and even displays mind-controlling abilities a couple of times. All of that fits with the popular image of vampires existing in much of the Western world.

As far as *who* he is is concerned, I'm by no means certain, but I've wondered whether Gaiman's Silas was partly inspired by Silas Ruthyn from Sheridan Le Fanu's Victorian Gothic tale *Uncle Silas*. (Please note that this is pure speculation on my part.)

The two share some notable connections. In Le Fanu's story, not only does Uncle Silas appear to be a vampire, but interestingly, he is also the legal guardian of his niece. Furthermore, in *The Graveyard Book*, near the end, Silas mentions that he was not always good, and did some terrible things which he deeply regrets. Uncle Silas in Le Fanu's tale is nothing short of ruthless and bloodthirsty. So, while it's only a guess, I think it's not unreasonable to theorize that Gaiman may possibly have found a little inspiration for his character in Silas Ruthyn.

Answer (score -1):

Silas is not a vampire, because it also says he is neither living nor dead; so that means he's undead.

And yes, he does say he eat one type of food but he never said it was blood, and blood isn't a food, it's a drink because it's liquid.

It's also never stated he had vampire teeth because Bod and that would have realised (because who wouldn't) and he went on mini holidays *all* the time (don't think vampires go on that many trips without consuming at least one innocent life).

Comment: So do you know what he _is_ then? You do a nice job of rationalising what he isn't, though [edit]ing in quotes would be better, but do you know what he is?

Comment: This does not answer my question. As TheLethalCarrot said, what is Silas then?